# I'm trying to connect two tables with Foreign Key constraints

Tags: mysql, relational-database, one-to-many

I am stuck in this electron desktop app where I need to have a patient table and collection/bill table where in patient table there can only be one entry and in another table, there can be as many as possible. Please Explain MySQL relation someone

And I didn't try anything so far
just a little bit of search on StackOverflow and GitHub

table 1 -> id pk,name varchar
table 2 -> collection_id pk,patient_id FK,name varchar,Amount

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a reference with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: sorry man i think i had a vague ideas about sql that time now i have learnt sql and also how ask questoins allright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design is correct and name in collection table can be called collection_name

table 1 -> id pk,name varchar
table 2 -> collection_id pk,patient_id FK, collection_name varchar, Amount